# mongoDb via nodejs sum a filed in a collecrion

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b844ee13e214434ac627efd"),
    "productName" : "milk",
    "amount" : 1,
    "totalPrice" : 123,
    "cartId" : "pp",
    "cartItemPic" : "danuna.png",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b844ee43e214434ac627efe"),
    "productName" : "chease",
    "amount" : 5,
    "totalPrice" : 240,
    "cartId" : "pp",
    "cartItemPic" : "chease.png",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b856c8f285a2554e0cbaced"),
    "productName" : "yugort",
    "amount" : 1,
    "totalPrice" : 7,
    "cartId" : "lala",
    "cartItemPic" : "yugortmulerMix.png",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

How do I **sum** the "totalPrice" where "cartId"=pp" -via node js.

Comment: This E-Commerce Shopping project is wrote by Nodejs and MongoDB. Maybe this  helpful for you.... https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Create a nodejs app

```
npm init -y
```

**Step 2**

Add mongodb dependency

```
npm install --save mongodb
```

**Step 3**

Create an index file

```
index.js
```

**Step 4** (in the index.js file)

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

mongodb.connect(dbUrl, function (err, db) {

    // Access to your collection
    const collection = db.collection('collectionName')

    collection.aggregate([
           {$match: { cartId: 'pp' }},
           {$group: { 
                     _id: null,
                     totalPrice: { $sum: '$totalPrice' }
           }}
     ], function(err, result) {
            // Your totalPrice will be in result object
       })
});
```

There are plenty of tutorials out there about mongodb... Just search for it.